# Problema de la tabla ARP con Wake on WAN

Tags: app

Estoy intentando hacer Wake on WAN para acceder a mi PC desde cualquier parte del mundo. He seguido todos los pasos que he visto en algunos tutoriales (modificar algunas características de la computadora y del enrutador). Cuando lo intento, funciona si enciendo el PC antes de 2 minutos de haberlo apagado, pero no si espero más. Por ejemplo, cuando apago la PC, espero un minuto y luego la enciendo, funciona. Pero si espero 3 minutos en lugar de 1 o 2, no funciona. He visto que puede haber un problema con la tabla ARP en el enrutador. Me gustaría preguntar si alguien sabe cómo se podría resolver esto. Gracias.

Comment: Estás en [es.so]. Traduce tu pregunta al castellano o terminará cerrada. Saludos

Comment: No sabemos nada de tu ambiente de prueba. ¿Red Local? ¿Desde Internet? ¿Routers? ¿Permite tu ISP conectarte desde Internet a un puerto local en tu router? ¿Esta configurado el router para redirigir el tráfico a un PC especifico? ¿TIene dirección IP fija tu PC?

Comment: He creado un servidor de DDNS (en no-ip) que tengo guardado en una app (wake on lan) y en el router. Desde la app indico que el PC se encienda con el nombre del servidor, la MAC y el puerto. El router recibe esto y he configurado NAT para que lleve la información que entra por el puerto indicado al PC. El PC tiene una ip estática asociada a la MAC, así que el router debería poder identificarlo.